# Is this question in the reopen queue and if not, why not?

Tags: support, closing-questions, review

[This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/360625/36423) was edited while being on hold by me. This should have pushed it to the reopen queue.  However, this does not seem to be the case:

- A reopen review task does not appear in [its timeline](https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/360625/timeline) – which it would after the review was completed.
- No reviewer who reviewed in the reopen queue today reviewed this post. Of course, all of them could have skipped this particular review, but I consider that unlikely.

I have two questions:

- Am I right and this question is not in the reopen queue as of this writing? (Anybody with 3 k reputation should be able to answer this.)
- If not, why?

*Note that this is not about discussing whether this question should be reopened or not; it’s just about the mechanics of pushing something to the reopen queue.*

Comment: Taking aside the automatic stuff, this question is very low quality, so even if it appeared in the queue, it might not get re-opened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See:

[Lots of questions in the reopen queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196074/lots-of-questions-in-the-reopen-queue/196078#196078)

> , this means that a closed question will automatically be added to the reopen queue when it is...
>
> - ...Edited (body edits only) within 5 days of closure by the author. Or,
> - ...Edited (body edits only) within 5 days of closure by a 3rd-party, provided the editor has not also flagged the question or voted to close it. Or,
> - ...Sufficiently popular, where popularity is calculated based on question score, top answer score, or views per month. We're still tweaking the exact thresholds for these.
>
> As always, a reopen vote will add a question to the reopen queue if it isn't already in the queue.

Assuming that's all still current, your edit wasn't soon enough to automatically add it to the review queue, although also see the "provided that" clauses there as well. You can still click "reopen" under the post to  vote to reopen it which I think should add it. Or presumably you can flag it if you don't have the reputation to vote but are confident it is now ready to reopen.

Comment: Ah, it’s apparently because I flagged it for closure in the first place. Now, I know where to put my feature request.

Comment: Even if you hadn't flagged it for closure it still wouldn't have hit the reopen queue.

Comment: Why? The second point would apply to me. Either way, [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313711/255554) is the feature request to fix this.

Comment: My apologies -- I misread the date it was posted. You're correct.